# What is the proper generic term for what is sometimes called an "XHR" or "AJAX" request?

Tags: browser, terminology

"AJAX" seems plainly inaccurate for the vast majority of these requests in 2023. However, like Kleenex it has certainly been genericized.

In my browser's Network tab, they are categorized as "XHR" requests, but my understanding is that this wouldn't even be technically accurate for requests being made using Fetch vs XMLHttpRequest requests.

So is there an actual, proper, generic term? And if not -- how is this possible? Programmers LOVE using explicit, proper terminology.

Comment: XHR is a technology used to support the technique AJAX.

Comment: I'm gonna go ahead and disagree with you there. At least in that being relevant to this question.

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/XMLHttpRequest

Comment: Think of the `X` in AJAX as being a placeholder for many types of data .. XML, JSON, arraybuffer, blob, text ... or it could be renamed AJAXJABT - but that's a mouthful

Comment: @FrankThomas I understand, but it is irrelevant to the question. The implication must that XHR and Fetch are two technologies used to make "AJAX requests". I suppose I can infer that, in your opinion, the answer to my question is "AJAX request".

Comment: @JaromandaX Thanks! It seems you would agree, then, that the correct answer is maybe "Ajax" (not as an acronym), since the original "AJAX" is plainly a misnomer? Interestingly enough, per the MDN page for the Fetch API (https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API), they avoid using the word "Ajax" completely. describing it as "an interface for fetching resources".  IMO this means we as an industry remain wanting for a definitive term!

Comment: *It seems you would agree* - nope, don't agree with your opinion, but will defend your right to express it to the death

Comment: Uh, thanks. I didn't say you would agree with my opinion, though. I said you would agree with the other commenter that the answer is "Ajax" (or "AJAX"). If you don't agree, can you clarify your response then?